# How to get the class name of parent div when clicked on any of its children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wish to get the class name of the parent class i.e *Main_Class* in this case using only **javascript**. Not **jquery**. How to so so ??

```
<div className="Main_Class">
    <div className="Child_1">
        <p>One</p>
    </div>
    <div className="Child_2 onclicked={handleClick}>
        <p>Two</p>
    </div>
    <div className="Child_3">
        <p>Three</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the parent element using `parentElement`, then get its class using `className`:

```
yourElement.parentElement.className;
```

Answer (score 0):

When the first `p` is clicked (adjust first selector as needed):

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].addEventListener("click",function(){
    console.log( this.parentNode.className );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code, it's `onClick` and not `onClicked`

And you should pass `this` to get the clicked element like so:

```js
function handleClick(el) {
  console.log(el.parentElement.className);
}
```

```html
<div class="Main_Class">
    <div class="Child_1">
        <p>One</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Child_2" onclick="handleClick(this)">
        <p>Two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Child_3">
        <p>Three</p>
    </div>
</div>
```